# Git notes missing after `git clone --mirror`

Tags: git, git-clone

I am trying to mirror a local repository with all available `refs` including `refs/notes/*`. However, the notes are not cloned as expected.

To reproduce the issue execute these commands in an empty directory:

```
$ git init repo && cd repo
$ git commit --allow-empty -m 'initial commit'
$ git notes add -m 'Initial commit on empty repo' HEAD
$ git clone --mirror .git ../mirror
```

Getting the diff between the refs shows that `notes` is missing from the mirrored repository:

```
$ diff repo/.git/refs mirror/refs
Common subdirectories: repo/.git/refs/heads and mirror/refs/heads
Common subdirectories: repo/.git/refs/tags and mirror/refs/tags
Only in repo/.git/refs: notes
```

`git -C mirror fetch` doesn't fetch the notes either, even though `fetch = +refs/*:refs/*` is specified in `mirror/config`.

The question now is: Is there something I am missing? I am using git 2.3.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `git clone` or `git fetch` obtain references, they generally leave them "packed".

Unpacked references are stored one per file in `.git/refs/` according to their full name, so that you get `.git/refs/heads/master` and `.git/refs/notes/commits` for instance.

Packed references are (currently) stored all in one file, `.git/packed-refs`.  This contains one reference per line, plus an extra "peeled" variant for some references (annotated tags, really).

If a reference appears in both places, Git "prefers" the unpacked one (so that it does not have to remove the entry from the packed file when updating a reference).  Updating a reference generally unpacks it: it's better and/or easier to keep updating a single-entry file like `.git/refs/heads/master` than to keep replacing one line in a multi-entry file.

Git is allowed to unpack or repack references at any time, so simply `diff`ing two `.git` trees is not guaranteed to do you any good.  (The same holds for packed and unpacked *objects* as well, but I see you're diffing just the `refs` sub-directories.)  So the diff output you quoted says nothing about whether the notes were cloned.  To see if the notes were cloned, go into the clone and use operations that read the notes.

In any case, if there is a `fetch = +refs/*:refs/*` line, you *should* be getting the notes copied.

Comment: `.git/packed-refs` was the missing link here. The most important thing to take away from this answer is that you shouldn't rely on git's file structure, which is why my diff command did not make sense. Instead one should use plumbing commands, e.g. `git for-each-ref`.